# Unit testing a directive that calls a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I have a service that looks at the current URL and retrieves a querystring parameter:

```
app.service('myService', function($location) {
    return {
        getCustID : function() {
            return $location.search().custID;
        }
    };
});
```

And I have been able to successfully unit test via:

```
describe('myService', function(){

    var $location, myService;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_myService_, _$location_) {
        this.myService = _myService_;
        $location = _$location_;
    }));

    it('should get a promoCode from the url', function(){
        $location.url('/?custID=DSGAG444355');
        expect(this.myService.getCustID()).toEqual('DSGAG444355');
    });
});
```

However, I have a directive which uses the service above. How can I test that?

Directive:

```
app.directive('imageDirective', function($compile, myService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var custID = myService.getCustID();
            var myText;

            if (custID == 3) {
                text = 'cust ID is 3';
            }

            var jqLiteWrappedElement = angular.element('<img src="/resources/img/welcome.png' alt=" ' + myText + '" />');
            element.replaceWith(jqLiteWrappedElement);
            $compile(jqLiteWrappedElement)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

UPDATE:

Here's a test i attempted based on the intial repsonse below:

describe('my directive test', function () {
    var $scope, compile, element, myMock;

```
beforeEach(module('myApp'));

beforeEach(module(function($provide){
    myMock = {}//Mock the service using jasmine.spyObj, or however you want
    $provide.factory('myService', function(){
        return myMock;
    })
}));    

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element("<img my-directive/>");
    $compile(element)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
}));


it('should get a parameter from the URL', function(){
    $location.url('/?custID=003');
    expect(myMock.getcustID()).toEqual('003');
});
```

});

```
TypeError: myService.getCustID is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the service using `$provide`

```
var myMock;
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
beforeEach(module(function($provide){
  myMock = {}//Mock the service using jasmine.spyObj, or however you want
  $provide.factory('myService', function(){
    return myMock;
  })
}));
```

and then follow the [instructions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) on angular's documentation on how to unit test directives.

Comment: @OamPsy your mock doesn't have the functions set up. you need to specify the functions you want your mock to have, which probably would be all the ones that the real service has: `myMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('myServiceMock', ['getCustID',/*etc all the functions yo want to mock*/ ])`

Comment: can you please create a plunker?

Comment: Don't really have the time. But have you read the documentation on how to test directives? basically you need to inject the `$compile` service and compile your directive and then check with some selectors or something if everything looks good. You probably know better what should be tested on your directive

Answer (score 0):

Use Jasmine mocks for unit testing.
Once the library is downloaded:

```
describe('mydirective', function(){

var $location, myService;

beforeEach(module('myApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_myService_, _$location_) {
    myService = _myService_;
    $location = _$location_;
  spyOn(myService, "getCustID").and.returnValue("123462");
}));
//Write stuff for your directive here
it('should have made a call to ', function(){
    expect(myService.getCustId).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

for more reference :http://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2014/12/10/Mocking-calls-with-Jasmine

Comment: i think there's an error on the spyOn line... Should it be myService or this.myService?

Comment: Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for getCustID()

Comment: Hey sorry for the this.myservice thingy.. just checked it now. Edited the code snippet and if that doesn't work try moving the spyOn inside the test block. It should work

Comment: No problem, made the change as recommended, error now is: Expected spy getCustID to have been called. Where am i/you actually loading the directive??

Comment: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/testing-directives.html
That basically goes into the beforeEach block.
  elem = angular.element(<elem to be Compiled>);
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile(elem)(scope);
    scope.$digest();